# C: modify file to read from external file

Tags: c

I'm working through *The C Programming Language - 2nd Edition*, trying to reason through the examples. I'm brand-new to C.

Much of the example code from the first chapter relies on `getchar()` to receive input. For instance, the following code, which returns the longest line of a block of text:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define     MAXLINE 1000

int max;
char line[MAXLINE];
char longest[MAXLINE];

int getline(void);
void copy(void);

int main()
{  
    int len;
    extern int max;
    extern char longest[];

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline()) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy();
        }
    if (max > 0)
        printf("%s", longest);
    return 0;        
}

int getline(void) {
    int c, i;
    extern char line[];

    for (i = 0; i < MAXLINE-1 && (c=getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        line[i] = c;
    
    if (c == '\n') {
        line[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(void) {
    int i;
    extern char line[], longest[];

    i=0;
    while ((longest[i] = line[i]) != '\0')
        ++i
}
```

Probably a simple answer, but what do I have to do to provide an external text file as input to this program?

EDIT: I've tried the following but am getting compilation errors:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define     MAXLINE 1000

int max;
char line[MAXLINE];
char longest[MAXLINE];
FILE *fp; 

int getline(void);
void copy(void);

int main()
{  
    int len;
    extern int max;
    extern char longest[];
    fp = fopen("./hello.txt", "r");

    max = 0;
    while ((len = getline()) > 0)
        if (len > max) {
            max = len;
            copy();
        }
    if (max > 0)
        printf("%s", longest);
    
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;        
}

int getline(void) {
    int c, i;
    extern char line[];
    extern FILE *fp;

    for (i = 0; i < MAXLINE-1 && (c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF && c != '\n'; ++i)
        line[i] = c;
    
    if (c == '\n') {
        line[i] = c;
        ++i;
    }
    line[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

void copy(void) {
    int i;
    extern char line[], longest[];

    i=0;
    while ((longest[i] = line[i]) != '\0')
        ++i;
}
```

Comment: A search for "c language file i/o" should get you a lot of help. As a starting point, look up the `fopen` function.

Comment: Code updated above with attempt to incorporate the i/o, still running into issues

Comment: Is there any valid reason that people do `++i` instead of `i++` ?

Comment: That's the convention given by the book; they have promised that in later chapters they explain why the prefix vs. the suffix.

Comment: @lispquestions ah.. yes, I remember K&R said that in its first chapter :)

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) and refer to [this C reference website](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). If on Linux, see also [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fopen("./hello.txt", "r");` opens and buffers a file named "./hello.txt" for reading.

Unless your file really is named with the `./` (aren't `/`in filenames illegal in UNIX and the like ?), you should **remove the `./`** from the string literal you pass as filename.

---

**Compilation errors** in your posted 'original' code are :

1. `getline()` can't really be *re-defined* if you include `stdio.h` on some platforms , over here MacOS, since it is defined/declared there as :

> `ssize_t getline(char ** __restrict __linep, size_t * __restrict __linecapp, FILE * __restrict __stream)`

Basically, **rename `getline()`** to something trivially different, say like `getln()`.

Alternatively, force the compiler, here Clang, to operate strictly within a standard , say C99, by adding a `-stdC99` option to the arguments during compilation.

This *seems* non-standard at least in C, maybe not in C++, but this is how it is on MacOS's `stdio.h`.

To be *precise*, version 10.14.6 , line 359 of `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/stdio.h`

2. A **missing `;`** after  `++i` @ line 50 col 12.

---

Further, as with most I/O in languages like C , your program is **missing some fundamental error checking** - very importantly , for example, checking `fp == NULL` in case `fopen()` fails, which will happen for example if hello.txt does not exist, which would be bad since `fclose(NULL)` is a seg fault.

You will understand this as you learn (stream-level) File I/O in C, perhaps subsequently.

If you are not at the level of learning `stdio.h` -based File I/O yet, why not just use the more convenient feature of **redirecting input from the console** ?
Just do `hello.txt > ./yourprogram` or `hello.txt | ./yourprogram` when running the original textbook code from the terminal.

Works on UNIX-based systems and even Windows and DOS, and is often used in such cases where the pains of implementing file I/O directly are not worth it.

Comment: Still having trouble: `hello.txt > ./a.out` gives `command not found: hello.txt`, `./a.out < hello.txt` doesn't print anything out. Both `./a.out | hello.txt` and `hello.txt | ./a.out` give `command not found: hello.txt`. I'm on OS X if that changes anything.

Comment: @lispquestions you are using the original, textbook code, correct ?

Comment: @lispquestions I have identified your compile errors of the original code and have edited my answer to reflect fixes

Comment: "getline() can't really be re-defined if you include stdio.h , since it is defined/declared there" --> That misleads as  `getline()` is not part of the C standard library.  It is, as posted here, a popular extension though.

Comment: Do you have the ability to compile on your MAC using only standard library?  If so, I suspect the library extension `getline()` will not longer readily be available and  `getline()` open for definition just like OP coded.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Sure, and that should be as easy as forcing Clang to strictly comply with some C standard, any of which should so , with , say, a simple `-stdC99` and a `-pedantic` for good measure. Will edit answer !