# How do you pass commands (or .sh files) as a program argument in CLion's 'Edit Configurations'? (C, Linux)

Tags: c, linux, sh, clion

I'm given some .sh files and I run it later in my code with execvp(argv[i], &argv[i+1]). Assume i is the index of the command in my program arguments and anything following it is the arguments I want to pass to the command (everything before i are parameters like 'how long I want the command to run' and aren't important for my question).

How do I pass the .sh file using 'Edit Configurations'? I've tried writing 'name.sh' as a program argument (the .sh files are in the same directory as my executable file). I've also tried using the whole address of .sh and my code still didn't work.

I'm trying to figure out if there's something wrong with my code or if I'm just writing my arguments in 'Edit Configurations' incorrectly. Thanks!

Comment: Commands and `.sh` files are very different things in terms of taking input, don't let the UNIX abstractions blind you.

Comment: how would I pass an .sh file as an argument? Is it enough to just write the name of the file, or would I need something else?

Comment: From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64084840/13929340) of mine, " You will understand once you learn File I/O in C, perhaps subsequently. 

If you are not at the level of learning `stdio.h` -based File I/O yet, why not just use the more convenient feature of **redirecting input from the console** ?
Just do `hello.txt > ./yourprogram` or `hello.txt | ./yourprogram` when running the same original code from the terminal. 

Works on UNIX-based systems and even Windows and DOS, and is often used in such cases where the pains of implementing file I/O directly are not worth it."

Comment: As a self-rebuttal to the otherwise rhetorical "*why not just redirect input from console ?*" It may or may not make you take File I/O for granted and as something easy and compromise your resolve to pay attention and learn it - **you have been warned** , do not do this, File I/O is seriously important - best of luck for when you learn it ! :)

Comment: Thank you! I've been super lazy and have been using CLion's built in arguments to run my code, but I'll try to compile and run it in the terminal.

Comment: badatcode, the sooner you learn you way with the terminal, the better it is.